# gmake is deleting some files implicitly on Solaris 10

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am running GNU `gmake` for my build process. I use file extensions as the following:

```
.pc: pro*c code (compiled by using oracle's proc compiler)
.cpp : c++ code (compiled by GNU g++ compiler)
.o: object file
.mc: c++ code (compiled by GNU g++ compiler)
.mo: object file
```

A `.pc` file gets compiled by Oracle `proc` compiler and output is having extension `.cpp` or  that gets compiled by `g++` compiler to generate `.o` file. All `.o` files eventually get linked together to make the executable file.

For some other requirement, I need to have some special code block within .pc file as below.

```
#ifdef SPCL_BLCK 
// some code
#endif // end of SPCL_BLCK
```

I need to have to different paths to have my executable variants, with and without special code part.
Without special code part, the paths are:

```
.pc -> .cpp -> .o -> executable
```

With special code part, the paths are:

```
.pc -> .mc -> .mo -> executable
```

I have my PROC flags defined as:

```
PROCFLAGS := code=cpp 'include=(<<list of comma-separated include dirs>>)'
```

normal rules (for path without special code):

```
.pc.c:
        proc $(PROCFLAGS) $<
%.o: %.c
        g++ -c $(CCFLAGS) $<
```

where, `CCFLAGS` are usual C++ compiler flags

rules (for path with special code):

```
%.mo: %.mc
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) -DSPCL_BLCK -o $@ -x c++ $<

%.mc: %.pc
    $(PROC) $(PROCFLAGS) define=SPCL_BLCK oname=$@ $<
```

All is well, but after the successful build, the `.mc` files gets deleted.
I see that's done by `rm` command, but is there any implicit rule that is driving the removal of the `.mc` files?
Can I have some command that could stop firing implicit rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to define the following in `gmakefile`:

```
.PRECIOUS:%.c %.mc
```

Otherwise, GNU `gmake` thinks that .mc files are intermediate files and drives the removal of these `.mc` files